# Elastic Search performance degraded after veriosn update from ES 1.4.2 to ES 7.9

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to upgrade the OLD ES 1.4.2 setup to new ES 7.9. For that we are testing the search performance.
I am testing the search performance by querying the search queries returning different no. of documents simultaneously by 5 different clients(REST API).I am using scroll API to get the results by calling it one after other to get all the matching results. I am just iterating through the results before making next scroll request. Some queries returning very large data, some returns medium data. There is a query which returns 90% of documents of the index. This scroll API query takes 2 hrs to complete in ES 1.4.2 and same query takes about 11 hrs to complete in ES 7.9. I was expecting performance increase after upgrading to ES 7.9 but found huge performance degradation. Anyone knows the reason behind this?. All the default settings I m using for both the ES versions. Please provide help here. Thanks

Sample Query :
#Query 1 :
http://localhost:9200/cgh_hs_hg19_20170821/_search?scroll=1m

```
{
    "size": 1000,
   
     
    "query" : {
      "match_phrase" : {
         "num_hits" : "1"
      }
   }
}

Mappings : 
{
  "settings":
  {
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "refresh_interval": "30s"
  },
 "mappings": 
 {
                "properties": 
                {
                    "build_version": 
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "externalprobe_id": 
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "gc_percent_1": 
                    {
                        "type": "float",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "gc_percent_2": 
                    {
                        "type": "float",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "gc_percent_3": 
                    {
                        "type": "float",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "has_snp_resite": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "hits": 
                    {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": 
                        {
                            "annotations": 
                            {
                                "properties":
                                {
                                    "accession": 
                                    {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "store": true
                                    },
                                    "cytoband": 
                                    {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "store": true
                                    },
                                    "description": 
                                    {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "store": true
                                    },
                                    "gene_name": 
                                    {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "store": true
                                    },
                                    "gene_symbol": 
                                    {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "store": true
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "chr_name": 
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "chr_order":
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "chr_start": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "chr_stop": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "cpg_count_100": 
                            {
                                "type": "float",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "cpg_count_200":
                            {
                                "type": "float",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "gc_percent": 
                            {
                                "type": "float",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "is_exonic": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "is_intragenic": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "is_masked": 
                            {
                                "type": "boolean",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "is_primary_hit": 
                            {
                                "type": "boolean",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "masked_length": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "midpoint": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "rank": 
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "score": 
                            {
                                "type": "float",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "strand": 
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "store": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "is_catalog": 
                    {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "is_hom_filtered":
                    {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "is_pseudoautosomal": 
                    {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "is_tm_filtered":
                    {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "md5_hash": 
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "num_hits": 
                    {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "on_backbone":
                    {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "perf_score":
                    {
                        "type": "float",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "query": 
                    {
                        "properties": 
                        {
                            "bool": 
                            {
                                "properties":
                                {
                                    "must":
                                    {
                                        "properties":
                                        {
                                            "nested": 
                                            {
                                                "properties": 
                                                {
                                                    "path": 
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "text"
                                                    },
                                                    "query":
                                                    {
                                                        "properties": 
                                                        {
                                                            "bool": 
                                                            {
                                                                "properties":
                                                                {
                                                                    "must": 
                                                                    {
                                                                        "properties": 
                                                                        {
                                                                            "range": 
                                                                            {
                                                                                "properties": 
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "midpoint": 
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "properties": 
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            "from": 
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "type": "text"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            "to": 
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "type": "text"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            },
                                                                            "term": 
                                                                            {
                                                                                "properties":
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "chr_name":
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        "type": "text"
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sequence": 
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "size": 
                    {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "species_code":
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "status": 
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    "tm_value":
                    {
                        "type": "float",
                        "store": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would help to see more concrete details, such as the query you're making, the mappings of your index, some volumetry figures, etc... In clear, help us help you!

Comment: Update your question please, adding technical details in comments doesn't help

Comment: Sort with _doc to get better throughput

Answer (score 0):

At first you should ask yourself if the default 1.X configuration of 5 shards is a good number for you ?
According to elastic the best target size for a shard is around 50GB.
Oversharding is usually a cause of performance degradation in elastic.

I guess you changed some deprecated mappings between 1.x and 7.X and you had reindex your data.
You must do a [forcemerge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) after that to ensure a good re-partition on the disk.

After those common maintenance, you will be able to investigate more.
Performance bottlenecks can come from a lot of different things (RAM, CPU, IO speed, etc...), and hardware context on your cluster 7.x is probably not the same than on the 1.x cluster.

Comment: I am testing on the same machine so same hardware and OS, difference is in the Java versions for ES1.4.2 Java8 and for ES 7.9 Java 14 I am using. Let me try changing the no of shards and see the performance for ES 7.9. Thanks.

Comment: what no i should use for max_num_segments if i do forcemerge after re-indexing?